# Prelaunch (Coming Soon) Page with Admin Access in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I need to add a "Coming Soon" prelaunch page with email collection to my Rails 3.2 project.

All the gems I've seen so far do not allow me to bypass the prelaunch page if the user is logged in. (signed in on particular page)

I would like to have a 100% working website for an authorized user but render a "coming soon" page for everyone else. What is the best way to achieve this?

P.S. I tried to use Devise that came with ActiveAdmin but got stuck with it's helpers

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-prelaunch-signup